# Showing percentage for the group using MS SQL

Tags: mssql-jdbc

I have the following query:

```
SELECT machine, start_date, sum(duration), 
st.status_code, st.status_text
FROM er_table er
LEFT JOIN status_table st on er.status_code=st.status_code
where machine in ('mach1','mach2','mach3')
group by machine, start_date, st.status_code, st.status_text
order by machine, start_date, status_text
```

It produces the following result:

[image]

However, I need to add a percentage for the group of machines for a particular date. E.g. on 15 Sep, mach1 was in idle for 20 secs, thus, 20/(20+800) would give me 2% idle time.

This is the result I need to get:

[image]

I saw a similar question from a similar post and i modified my code as follows, but it didn't quite give the result I'm looking for:

```
SELECT machine, start_date, sum(duration), 
SUM(duration) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(duration)) OVER () AS Percentage,
st.status_code, st.status_text
FROM er_table er
LEFT JOIN status_table st on er.status_code=st.status_code
where machine in ('mach1','mach2','mach3')
group by machine, start_date, st.status_code, st.status_text
order by machine, start_date, status_text
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT machine, start_date, sum(duration), 

SUM(duration) * 100.0 / SUM(duration) OVER(partition by machine, start_date) AS Percentage,

st.status_code, st.status_text
FROM er_table er
LEFT JOIN status_table st on er.status_code=st.status_code
where machine in ('mach1','mach2','mach3')
group by machine, start_date, st.status_code, st.status_text
order by machine, start_date, status_text
```

How about doing it like this?

i used partition by in sum() over()

result:

| machine | start_date | duration | percentage | status_code | status_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mach1 | 2021-09-15 | 20 | 2.439024390243 | 1 | IDLE |
| mach1 | 2021-09-15 | 800 | 97.560975609756 | 1 | RUNNING |
| mach1 | 2021-09-16 | 40 | 4.255319148936 | 1 | IDLE |
| mach1 | 2021-09-16 | 900 | 95.744680851063 | 1 | RUNNING |
| mach2 | 2021-09-15 | 100 | 12.500000000000 | 1 | IDLE |
| mach2 | 2021-09-15 | 700 | 87.500000000000 | 1 | RUNNING |